# Current_user is not being initiated correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I know that there have been many similar questions on this topic but none of the answer pertain.

I've decided to follow Michael Hartl's advice and implement my own authentication code instead of using a predefined package. But I'm running into a problem with his solution from the railstutorial.

I've double/triple checked my code directly with the tutorial code in github, I'm implementing correctly as far as I can see but I have some big problems.

**Current_user is not being initiated correctly**

helpers/sessions_helpers.rb

```
    ...
    def current_user=(user)
      @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
      #this line of code will change in the tutorial section 9 but its okay for now 
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])

    end

    def signed_in?
      !current_user.nil?
    end
```

Any code using the helpers in the views `<% if signed_in? %>`
 always returns false, even if authentication has worked. And any attempt to access data via user methods like `current_user.first_name.capitalize` fail with ``` undefined method ``first_name' for nil:NilClass ```

Please note this is still section 8 in the tutorial (not at section 9 just yet, I don't really want to add more code to this authentication situation when the basics are not working. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Well, apparently authentication didn't work and `@current_user` hasn't been assigned. You should check and trace your code again.

Comment: For example, what's in `cookies[:remember_token]` and can you indeed find a user by that value?

Comment: Thanks Sergio you're right it didn't work. Thanks for the thought, had to go a little deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like some unit tests would help narrow your focus and highlight which parts are working ok, and which ones aren't. Or if you want, start with integration tests. The description you gave makes it sound like you're testing via browser and maybe looking at logs.

I think you'll find that writing the tests as you go is worth the time. It will also make it easier to see if you break something later on that used to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Indeed I agree. I was having problems with factory girl classes and tests were failing and got tired of messing with it this morning, but getting it working was helpful. In the end I found that I wasn't calling the sign_in method upon sign in. Painfully SNAFU. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, replace "User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
" with something valid to make sure your calls work.

Also, your methods are all methods on session so only usable within session controller.

If you want them accessible in all views, put the methods in application_helper.rb.

Comment: I use include SessionsHelper in ApplicaitonController to make the methods accessible.

Comment: Yeah, i found that cookies weren't even being set because of an ID10T error! thanks for the thoughts on this one.